# MySql Error: #105 (Code 150). When I create my database schema I receive an error code of 150.

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, mysql-error-1005

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `YouthMinistry` ;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `YouthMinistry` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf16 COLLATE utf16_general_ci ;
USE `YouthMinistry` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `YouthMinistry`.`group`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `YouthMinistry`.`group` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `YouthMinistry`.`group` (
  `groupid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `group_name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
  `group_desc` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`groupid`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `YouthMinistry`.`groupmembers`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `YouthMinistry`.`groupmembers` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `YouthMinistry`.`groupmembers` (
  `groupid` INT NOT NULL ,
  `memberid` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`groupid`, `memberid`) ,
  INDEX `groupid_idx` (`groupid` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `groupid`
    FOREIGN KEY (`groupid` )
    REFERENCES `YouthMinistry`.`group` (`groupid` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `YouthMinistry`.`role`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `YouthMinistry`.`role` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `YouthMinistry`.`role` (
  `roleid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `role_name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
  `role_desc` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`roleid`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `YouthMinistry`.`rolemembers`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `YouthMinistry`.`rolemembers` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `YouthMinistry`.`rolemembers` (
  `roleid` INT NOT NULL ,
  `memberid` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`roleid`, `memberid`) ,
  INDEX `groupid_idx` (`roleid` ASC) ,
  FOREIGN KEY (`roleid` )
    REFERENCES `YouthMinistry`.`role` (`roleid` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `YouthMinistry`.`users`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `YouthMinistry`.`users` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `YouthMinistry`.`users` (
  `memberid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `email` VARCHAR(100) NULL ,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `last_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`memberid`, `username`, `password`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `username_UNIQUE` (`username` ASC) ,
  INDEX `memberid_idx` (`memberid` ASC) ,
  INDEX `memberid_idx1` (`memberid` ASC) ,
  FOREIGN KEY (`memberid` )
    REFERENCES `YouthMinistry`.`groupmembers` (`memberid` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (`memberid` )
    REFERENCES `YouthMinistry`.`rolemembers` (`memberid` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `YouthMinistry`.`eventgroup`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `YouthMinistry`.`eventgroup` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `YouthMinistry`.`eventgroup` (
  `eventid` INT NOT NULL ,
  `groupid` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`eventid`, `groupid`) ,
  INDEX `groupid_idx` (`groupid` ASC) ,
  FOREIGN KEY (`groupid`)
    REFERENCES `YouthMinistry`.`group` (`groupid`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `YouthMinistry`.`event`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `YouthMinistry`.`event` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `YouthMinistry`.`event` (
  `eventid` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `event_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `event_desc` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`eventid`) ,
  INDEX `eventid_idx` (`eventid` ASC) ,
  FOREIGN KEY (`eventid` )
    REFERENCES `YouthMinistry`.`eventgroup` (`eventid` )
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I'm working on creating a database for a website that I'm making and when I run the create script it gives me the following error:
Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'youthministry.users' (errno: 150)

I've looked at the following sources for possible solutions to this error:
http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?68260-mySQL-multiple-foreign-keys
http://forums.devarticles.com/mysql-development-50/mysql-foreign-key-problem-errno-150t-7704.html

I've checked the primary and foreign key declarations just to make sure everything is correct.

Any help is much appreciated. Also this is still a prototype and any comments on the initial schema is welcome.  I'm still new at database design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only create a foreign key on one table that references a key on another table.  This specific problem is that `memberid` is not a key on either `groupmembers` or `rolemembers` tables.  Simply add `KEY (memberid)` to those tables and you'll be good to go.

Another issue us that foreign key types must match.  `eventgroup` has `groupid varchar`, but is referencing the `groups` table, which has `groupid INT`.  Correct this.

---

As for suggestions, I very strongly recommend that each primary key be only one column: your auto-increment surrogate key.  You should make these unsigned integers too.

Comment: Thanks that worked great.  Thanks for the suggestions as well I've modified the schema to take them into account.