# ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, mysql-error-1005

I fighting with the most common error but failing to solve the issue.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tvguide_db`.`tvchanel` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tvguide_db`.`tvchanel` (
  `idtvchanel` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL ,
  `chanelname` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL ,
  `icon` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL ,
  `category` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL ,
  `genre` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `description` VARCHAR(256) NULL ,
  `chanellanguage` VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idtvchanel`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `idtvchanel_UNIQUE` (`idtvchanel` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `subscriber_db`.`chanellist_planid` ;

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `subscriber_db`.`chanellist_planid` (
  `chanelid` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`chanelid`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `chanelid_UNIQUE` (`chanelid` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_chanellist_planid_chanelid`
    FOREIGN KEY (`chanelid` )
    REFERENCES `tvguide_db`.`tvchanel` (`idtvchanel` )
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I'am getting this error

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'subscriber_db.chanellist_planid' (errno: 150)
```

On this SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; command gave me this.

```
131006  5:38:49 Error in foreign key constraint of table subscriber_db/chanellist_planid:

    FOREIGN KEY (`chanelid` )
    REFERENCES `tvguide_db`.`tvchanel` (`idtvchanel` )
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB:
Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in
tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables
cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html
for correct foreign key definition.
```

Any solution.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please refer this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888593/mysql-error-105-code-150-when-i-create-my-database-schema-i-receive-an-erro

Comment: You are refering your foreign key to another database.

Comment: @juergend It can do that.

Comment: i refered most of the stackoverfow questions but all the constraints seems to be right.

Comment: @Deepak i read the link but the constraints that have to be taken care of are there in my code.

Comment: Do you have other foreign keys referencing chanellist_planid?

Comment: Check the default charsets of the 2 databases. They are probably different. For nonbinary (character) string columns, the character set and collation of the referencing and referenced columns must be the same. If you don't want to to change the default charsets and collations of the databases, define the two columns (`tvguide_db.tvchanel.idtvchanel` and `subscriber_db.chanellist_planid.idtvchanel`) with same charset and collation.

Comment: @PRASANTH : Can you please tell me the charset and collation of these fields tvchanel(idtvchanel) and chanellist_planid(chanelid)

Comment: I have defined schema like this
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `subscriber_db` ;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `subscriber_db` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `tvguide_db` ;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `tvguide_db` ;

Comment: Tried to change the default character set but no change.